# T-SQL - Must have term in group by or aggregate function to select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given the following select statement:

```
Select t.name,  SUM(st.row_count) as row_count
From sys.dm_db_partition_stats st  
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = st.object_id
join ClientUpdateConfig c on t.name = c.TableName
Where  (index_id < 2)  and  schema_id = schema_id('dbo') 
and t.type ='U'
group by t.name
```

I would also like to select c.RowID as an additional field.  The query works as it is but if I changed like 1 to:

```
Select t.name,  SUM(st.row_count) as row_count, c.RowID as current_row
```

I get the error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'ClientUpdateConfig.RowID'
>   is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can someone explain why I'd need the select value in the aggregate function (I'm assuming SUM) or in the group by to select it?  I don't understand this restriction - maybe I can adjust my query design if I can understand why this is happening.

Comment: And can't you add `GROUP BY t.name, c.RowID`? The error message is pretty self-explanatory. If anything in the select list is not an aggregate, it must also be considered by GROUP BY. If there are duplicate RowIDs and you only want one, you need to tell SQL Server which one you want (usually MIN or MAX).

Comment: One of the hardest things for people to get in relational DBs is aggregation.  @W00te, you are selecting multiple source rows per output row when you use `GROUP BY`.   You need  to specify which `RowId` you want since  there will be multiple `RowID` values per output row.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers.  This is one of those things I've run into a few times but its always a year in-between since I only work with databases off-and-on. It always comes back to bite me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it doesn't know which RowId to select.

You need either:

```
. . .
group by t.name, RowId
```

or:

```
select . . ., min(RowId) -- or max(RowId)
```

Even if you know that there is only one RowId per name, the database does not know that, so you have to explicitly say what you want to do in the query.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between these two options? min() vs group by

Comment: @ase69s . . . Strange question.  `min()` and `group by` both do aggregations, so they should have similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

The results of the query are based on an aggregate of multiple ROWS. You take many rows with the same `t.name` and also their many different `st.row_count` values and create one row (with `t.name` which is the same for every aggregated row and a sum of all their `t.row_count` values). For such an aggregate, there's no sensible value of `c.Row_ID`. Each row that you group has a different value and there's no way to determine what value should be used. If the `RowID` is numeric, you could average or sum or perhaps take the smallest (min) or largest (max) of all the IDs. Not that it would *make any sense*. A value like this would simply exist for an aggregate.